# Choose from Excel dropdown programmatically

Tags: vba, list, excel

I want to write a macro that will pick a particular value (in my case, stored in cell `A1`) from a dropdown list (in my case, in cell `D6`).

Here's what I have so far:

```
sr_par2 = Array ("TEXT", 'TEXT2", "TEXT3")

sr = Range("A1").Value

(...)

Dim i As Integer
i = 0
Range("D6").Select

Do While (sr <> ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1)
    Range("D6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = sr_par2(i)
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. Also What is `sr`? `sr <> ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1`?

Comment: sr is value that is in Cell1 which is needed to be copied.

Comment: And sr <> ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 in my opinion should check if the value in Active Cell (in this case "D6") is chosen now on the list

Comment: `sr<>Activecell.Value` is what you want. Let me go through your quesiton again

Comment: How is the value of `sr` getting set? Cannot see it in your code.

Comment: I have a cell ("A1") with value, for example, A. Then sr = Range("A1").Value. 

And in "D6" from that code is the place where's a list with values from sr_par2

Comment: @Siddharth Rout it didn't work :( It's still pasting a value instead choosing it from list

Comment: Why are you overwriting `Range("D6")` in a loop?

Comment: Good question. I don't remember. But even after deleting it doesn't work neither :( but it may be a little step closer to finish ;)

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question on what exactly are you trying to do.. including how are you selecting values and where would that value go.

Comment: Ah! you are using a datavalidation list! now i understand what you are trying to do. I have replied to a similar post.. let me check if i can find that

Comment: Couldn't find the post so I put an answer. You may have to refresh the page to see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? I have commented the code so that you will not have a problem understanding it. Still if you do then simply ask :)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngIn As Range, rngOut As Range
    Dim MyAr
    Dim sFormula As String
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Replace this with the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Set your input and output range here
        Set rngIn = .Range("A1")
        Set rngOut = .Range("D6")

        '~~> Get the validation list if there is one
        On Error Resume Next
        sFormula = rngOut.Validation.Formula1
        On Error GoTo 0

        If sFormula = "" Then
            '~~> If no validation list then directly populate the value
            rngOut.Value = rngIn.Value
        Else
            'validation list TEXT1,TEXT2,TEXT3
            MyAr = Split(sFormula, ",")

            '~~> Loop through the list and compare
            For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
                If UCase(Trim(rngIn.Value)) = UCase(Trim(MyAr(i))) Then
                    rngOut.Value = MyAr(i)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i

            '~~> Check if the cell is still blank. If it is then it means that
            '~~> Cell A1 has a value which is not part of the list
            If Len(Trim(rngOut.Value)) = 0 Then
                MsgBox "The value in " & rngOut.Address & _
                " cannot be set as the value you are copying is not part of the list"
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: looks like it that what I'm looking for :) but I'll answer in an hour to get sure ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this should do what you want :

```
sr_par2 = Array("TEXT", "TEXT2", "TEXT3")

sr = Range("A1").Value

Dim i As Integer
i = 0

On Error GoTo Handler
Do While (sr <> sr_par2(i))
    i = i + 1
Loop
Range("D6").FormulaR1C1 = sr_par2(i)

Exit Sub
Handler:
MsgBox "Value not in the list", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Value not found"
```